# Creating alert policies in Error Reporting in Stackdriver

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-error-reporting

I have a requirement to create an alerting policies when there are 30 connection timeout exceptions.We are currently throwing exception when there is connection timeout during a web service call(consuming restful webservices) so i want to get alerts when there are like 30 connection timeout exceptions. Is there any way i can create such policies in Stakdriver.We are currently using java8, spring boot, google kubernetes engine, stackdriver logging.
I've created the metric called SAX-Exception an When i'm trying to create the stackdriver alert policies for this metrics i don't see any option to aggregate the number of exception over a period of time.

```
                         This below image shows how the metrics is defined
```

[image]

Below images show how the alerts policies are defined
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For this answer I will assume that your connect errors are being logged to Stackdriver Logging with sufficient detail that can be parsed by Stackdriver.

Your software that is throwing the exception needs to record this using Stackdriver Logging if you want to use Stackdriver Alerting. Adding Stackdriver logging code is very easy in just about any language including Java.

[Stackdriver Logging Client Libraries (Java)](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java).

Assuming that you have Stackdriver Logging logs with desired event details:

- Go to Stackdriver Logging.
- Create a metric based upon your desired error based upon content in your log entries.

Documentation: [link](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/).

Once you have a metric created, you can then create an alert based upon this metric. You can aggregate based upon number of events per period of time. In your case 30 events in one minute (or whatever you need as your failure indicator).

Documentation: [link](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/charts-and-alerts).

Comment: Thank you for taking sometime to respond to my post. I don't see any option in stack driver alert dashboard to aggregate the events over a period of time. I have updated my question with the screenshots.Please let me know what where i'm going wrong

Comment: Your screenshot show this. Look at Advanced Aggregation -> Alignment period.

Comment: I have updated my post with the new screenshot. As you can see i have set the event frequency to 30 counts and i generated 30 exception over a period of 15 mins i didn't get any alerts.Please let me where i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Don't replace parts of your question, just add to it. Otherwise, nobody will understand to flow of solving your issue. How is the alert configured? Show how the metric is defined. Show how the alert is defined.

Comment: I have updated. Can you please see my post whether it gives enough information.

Comment: Your screenshots to match. Please report problems as they exist and not in different states while debugging. Your threshold is set to over 30 in 15 minutes. Spend the time to read the documentation. Then configure your metric and alert correctly.